# not able to understand angular directives ng-not-empty-add, ng-valid-parse-add, ng-not-empty-remove

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation

following angular directives are added at the time of entering values in the field. Strange thing is, it is not allowing to enter anything in the field and upon inspecting the element this is what it shows

class="form-control input-sm ng-valid ng-empty ng-dirty ng-not-empty-add ng-valid-parse-add ng-not-empty-remove ng-touched" ng-model="testJavaBean.criteria1"

I could easily understand ng-valid, ng-empty, ng-dirty and touched but I am trying to find the meaning of ng-not-empty-add and ng-valid-parse-add ng-not-empty-remove. I did not find any reference on https://docs.angularjs.org
or in any other forums.